# How to get JSONObject nested value

Tags: java, json

May I know how to get the value for `contour_chin->x`? The JSON output is as follows:

```
{
    "image_id": "Dd2xUw9S/7yjr0oDHHSL/Q==",
    "request_id": "1470472868,dacf2ff1-ea45-4842-9c07-6e8418cea78b",
    "time_used": 752,
    "faces": [{
        "landmark": {
            "mouth_upper_lip_left_contour2": {
                "y": 185,
                "x": 146
            },
            "contour_chin": {
                "y": 231,
                "x": 137
            },
  //   .............landmarks omitted...........
            "right_eye_pupil": {
                "y": 146,
                "x": 205
            },
            "mouth_upper_lip_bottom": {
                "y": 195,
                "x": 159
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

The code I've tried is :

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("faces");
JSONObject jObj3 = (JSONObject) jArr.get(0);
JSONObject jObj4 = jObj3.getJSONObject("contour_chin");
String result = jObj4.getString("x");
return result;
```

It output the error No value for contour_chin. May I know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need:

```
JSONObject jObj4 = jObj3.getJSONObject("landmark").getJSONObject("contour_chin");
```